# Is there a way to stream data from AWS EC2 to local memory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to generate synthetic data in an AWS EC2 instance and stream it directly into the memory of my local machine for deep learning training. Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to send data from an Amazon EC2 instance to a computer that is _not_ in AWS (eg in your home/office)? What do you mean by "stream it directly into the memory"? How do you want to transfer the data? For example, are you running a web server or an app that is 'listening' to the data?

Comment: To extend on @JohnRotenstein comment, typically an application would communicate via sockets. The type of data you are talking about would probably need to be processed so i don't think you would need to build a client/server socket connection that streams live data. Maybe a restful api & micro-service is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to avoid any disk i/o, so I'm planning on transferring the data as a Bytesio stream. The program I'm running is very lightweight (just a simple python script), so would socket programming be the best option? For my purposes, I'm also not worried about a bottleneck during data processing.